# Segfaults related to Cameras IPC

Tags: firefox, suspend, freeze, camera, segmentation-fault

I keep getting these strange seg faults with Firefox. Every time I open the lid of my laptop after suspend, Firefox freezes and only force quit helps.

This has started a couple of weeks ago.

When I do *dmesg | grep segfault*, I get errors related to *"Cameras IPC"*.

**What could this be?**

Does Firefox try to access my webcamera?

Here are error messages:

```
[129627.988672] firefox[25135]: segfault at 0 ip 00007
fd23cf4398b sp 00007ffdf3695598 error 6 in libxul.so[7fd23a7e9000+653b000]
[134905.990042] Chrome_~dThread[26745]: segfault at 0 ip 00007ff22ed607bd sp 00007ff2408c0b00 error 6 in libxul.so[7ff22dfe9000+653b000]
[170542.318548] Chrome_~dThread[22231]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f4935b607bd sp 00007f49476f9b00 error 6 in libxul.so[7f4934de9000+653b000]
[170542.345143] Cameras IPC[22624]: segfault at 0 ip 0000561b1bfec9fb sp 00007f826c48e870 error 6 in firefox[561b1bfe7000+32000]
[170542.345340] Chrome_~dThread[22435]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f8535a607bd sp 00007f85476b8b00 error 6 in libxul.so[7f8534ce9000+653b000]
[220194.968631] Chrome_~dThread[24003]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f978f7607bd sp 00007f97a1352b00 error 6
[220194.968634] Cameras IPC[24049]: segfault at 0 ip 000056030e8429fb sp 00007f5fc9962870 error 6
[220194.968636] Cameras IPC[30094]: segfault at 0 ip 000055cb1923c9fb sp 00007f3446b9f870 error 6
[220194.968639] Cameras IPC[9936]: segfault at 0 ip 00005603c8aa39fb sp 00007f80cd6bc870 error 6
```

Here is the info:

```
Firefox version 63.0
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
NVidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390
```

Comment: Please post your Firefox version, distro name and version and if you use Nvidia drivers their version.

Comment: @KuriboKutsu Got it. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was answered before here - [Firefox becoming unresponsive after suspending on Kubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088324/firefox-becoming-unresponsive-after-suspending-on-kubuntu-18-10/1088716#1088716), but since it was me, i will cite myself
"

Unfortunately, its bug in Firefox - [Bug #1492580](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492580) "Infinite loop in GLContext::RawGetErrorAndClear from endless GL_CONTEXT_LOST with Nvidia Linux drivers and suspend/resume"

There is no solution so far unless Mozilla undo change which caused it - Bug 1484782, which is part of preparation to enable WebRender on Linux

Bug was not present in Firefox 62 and was not fixed in time to "ride trains" of Firefox 63, so you may want either downgrade to Firefox 62 or to shutdown Firefox each time your going to suspend your system."

Good news is that according to bug i mentioned they already working on fixing it and patch is coming soon. Due to impact if probably will be ported to current release version so, hopefully, it will be no longer problem in reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Downgrading is probably not a good idea because each Firefox release comes with security fixes. Killing the process via top and restarting is another workaround.